# how to pass props to a specific component in redux when iterating

Tags: reactjs, state, redux, prop

So I have this component in which I use the map function to call another component :

```
class configstepper extends React.Component {
...
//in render
 if(this.props.selected_devices){
   return(
            this.props.selected_devices.map( (row, index) => (
              <DeviceProps key={index} row={row} index={index} /> 

            )))}
         ...}
```

Now my DeviceProps component is fetching data so it has a props to render 
my problem is i want the props to be specific to a each DeviceProps not to all of them :

```
class deviceProperties extends Component { 
 ...

//in render
<RaisedButton style={styles.Button}label="Read From Device" primary={true} onClick={this.handleRead.bind(this)}/>
<TextField id={this.props.index} value={this.props.read_data}  readOnly/>
...
//handleRead where i trigger the action 
    handleRead(){

    this.props.read_device()
}

//mapstate to props
function mapStateToProps(state){
return {
     read_data:state.config.test}}

 connect(mapStateToProps,actions)(deviceProperties)
```

Data is fetched on button click when i render all the DeviceProps components get the same data while i only want to get it on the clicked component.
I couldn't figure a work around this one

Comment: Please, Improve your description. is DeviceProps  the same than `deviceProperties `? How `mapStateToProps` is applied? on what? Share the whole implem of DeviceProps .

Comment: yes deviceProperties is DeviceProps my bad 
I modified my code I hope it's more clear

Comment: Hey did you get the answer? I am stuck with the same problem

Answer (score 0):

The `mapStateToProps` function accepts a second argument being the props you passed into the component from the parent, you could use these to the fetch a slice of your state that is specific to each of your `DeviceProps` instances.  Equally the `mapDispatchToProps` also accepts the props as a second argument allowing you to create actions specific to each of your `DeviceProps` instances.

For example, say you were passing in a prop called `deviceId` into your `DeviceProps` component, with `deviceId` being a unique identifier for a specific device:

```
<DeviceProps key={index} row={row} index={index} deviceId={deviceId} />
```

Then you could use this unique identifier in your map state and props functions like so:

```
class DeviceProps extends Component {
   render() {
      ...
   }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps){
  return {
    device: state.devices[ownProps.deviceId]
  }
}  

function mapActionsToProps(dispatch, ownProps) {
  return bindActionCreators({
    readDeviceData: () => DeviceActions.readDeviceData(ownProps.deviceId)
  }, dispatch)
}

connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(DeviceProps)
```

Comment: the problem is in the textfield value when i assign to  it the props resulting from the action all textfields in the deviceprops instances will have the same value

Comment: Sounds like you might need to structure your redux store so that you can store data per device.  If they all share the same store property then yes they will end up displaying the same data.

Comment: any ideas on how to do that ?